# Rotating Text in LCD LM016 in 8051 (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, 8051

Edit: There wasn't any predefined instruction for this task so had to do it manually, here's the final output: http://www.tlians.com/TF.gif

I've to rotate text left & right on display LM016 attached to a microcontroller 8051, I want my required to text to rotate right & then towards left, Using big loops I did:

```
80 Address = T
81 Address = A
82 Address = N
83 Address = I

C1 Address = 0
C2 Address = 2
```

80-83 Addresses are directed via register R0, C1-C2 addresses are directed using Rr1 register. Everytime it repeats it increases the value of both registers so the next time text is generated it looks like text is moving towards right side, this loop continues 16 times so text disappears on the right side, now on every execution of the same loop R0 & R1 are decreased by 1 so text looks like it's moving towards left side.

Once cursor reaches 80 position after that (when it reaches 79) text on first line disappears at once, & program behaves unstably (I can fix that but my way is inefficient)

Using commands 18H & 1CH the text is shifted towards left & right at the whole, I want to shift the text character by character, can you guide me please towards any efficient method then the one I'm using & facing few issues?

What I want is this, my logic works fine & can extend it to work with perfect shifting but it's not efficient because I'm writing data again & again. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uBBA.gif

Answer (score 0):

Did it myself, there wasn't any predefined function for this task, here's the optimized output.
http://www.tlians.com/TF.gif